# Нахождение новых координат точки после афинных преобразований имея матрицу преобразования

Tags: python, opencv

Совсем новичок в OpenCV, нужно решить задачу, но пока непонятен один момент
Есть координаты для 3 точек в 2 изображениях: начальном и конечном, также есть координаты 4 точки в начальном изображении, нужно найти её координаты в конечном изображении. Предполагаю, что для этого нужна матрица преобразования, я её нашёл, но теперь не знаю, как найти координаты 4 точки во 2 изображении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь нужно применить матрицу преобразования к координатам точки (умножить вектор координат на матрицу).

Например, с использованием [cv2.transform](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20transform(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20m))

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, сейчас буду стараться применить). Мне эта тема не раз понадобится, не подскажите, где вы её изучали?

Comment: Базовый источник информации и примеров - как раз docs.opencv.org. Кроме того, есть какие-то туториалы, которые могут дать представление о наборе возможностей opencv [пример](http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/264.html)

Comment: Если ответ подошёл, его можно пометить как принятый (зелёная галочка)